# Can not access /data/data/app_package_name/files/libs/xyz in Android Lollipop

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop

I am working on an Android App and trying to access an executable at /data/data/app_package_name/files/libs/xyz and executing a command formed using this path.
For execution of command I am using the following code

```
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
String command = "/data/data/app_package_name/files/libs/xyz -edir/data/data/app_package_name/files/libs/ "+ var1 +" "+ var2+" -someFlag , -fl -g, -head";
Process pr = rt.exec(command);
BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(pr.getInputStream()));
line=input.readLine()
```

I am getting `line` as `null`but in only ***Android Lollipop*** .Its working in Kitkat or below Android versions.
Please comment if any more information is required. 
I covered this part of code in try,catch block also but no exceptions is there.

Comment: is ur device rooted?

Comment: No its not rooted. But i tried the same code on device having < Android 5 and it works like charm.